# How do I find the property of a JS object when clicked on

Tags: javascript, jquery

HTML

```
<div class="outerDiv">
    <div class="innerDiv">

    </div>
    <button id="appendObject">Click Me</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
var newArray = [
{
    id: 0,
    otherProperty: "this is a prop"
},
{
    id: 1,
    otherProperty: "this is a different prop"
    }
];
$("#appendObject").click(function() {
    $(".innerDiv").append("<div class='this-object'>" + newArray[0].otherProperty) + "</div>";
})

$("body").on("click", ".this-object", function() {
    alert(this.id);
})
```

I am trying to add properties of an object to an HTML div. I then want a user to be able to click on that HTML div and be able to change the properties of that object. Is there anyway I can do this? Thanks!

https://jsfiddle.net/of5x5egr/

Comment: what do you mean, change the properties? Css, height width... be a little more clear.

Comment: I want to be able to figure out which JavaScript object is being clicked on so I can allow a user to change specific properties of the object. For example: the first object in newArray - I want to allow the user to change the value of otherProperty by entering a value in an input field

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error here:

```
 $(".innerDiv").append("<div class='this-object'>" + newArray[0].otherProperty) + "</div>";
```

Should be

```
 $(".innerDiv").append("<div class='this-object'>" + newArray[0].otherProperty + "</div>");
```

https://jsfiddle.net/of5x5egr/2/